# Ondemand billing provider

Tags: payment, payment-processing

I've been looking around for a simple ondemand billing solution.

My scenario is the following:

My customers use virtual credits on my website.

Payment option 1)
Customers can buy virtual credits buy suppliying a credit card.

Payment option 2)
Customers can register their credit card for automatically getting billed when credits are running low.

I know google does this for their API usages. Any one have a good idea of a provider that can achieve this in a simple way? I want to outsource the whole process to not run into any PCI compliance issues. Also I would like the hosted solution to be wihtin our site (ifram in  a popup). The majority of our customers are companies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the US you can use [Authorize.Net's Customer Information Manager (CIM) API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/) to create payment profiles for your customers. Then you can charge against those profiles at any time to add credits when they are running low. They offer a [hosted CIM option](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/News-and-Announcements/New-Hosted-Option-for-CIM/td-p/12934) which greatly reduces your PCI compliance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at [Stripe.com](http://stripe.com/) lately.  They offer a very simple to use API which seems to be very well thought out.  They offer on-demand and subscription billing, good documentation, and their costs are not out of line (2.9% + $.30 per txn) considering you don't have to get a merchant account.  They are US-based.